# extraSecretMounts in Grafana

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, configmap, kubernetes-secrets

My goal is to make sure a client secret is not stored in plaintext in Grafana's ConfigMaps. So far, I figured out you can't just reference a value from a Secret in a ConfigMap. So another solution was to mount a secret to a file in the application and reference it in grafana.ini. Like [HERE](https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/22473).

Basically, I did it like that belowd.

grafana.ini:

```
  [auth.generic_oauth]
  enabled = true
  client_secret = $__file{/etc/secrets/auth_generic_oauth/client_secret}
```

Existing secret, or created along with helm:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: auth-generic-oauth-secret
type: Opaque
stringData:
  client_secret: <value>
```

Config for extraSecretMounts

```yaml
- extraSecretMounts:
  - name: auth-generic-oauth-secret-mount
     secretName: auth-generic-oauth-secret
     defaultMode: 0440
     mountPath: /etc/secrets/auth_generic_oauth
     readOnly: false
```

But the problem is that when I redepploy Grafana, it goes into CrashLoopBackOf state, and the logs say:

```sh
Failed to start grafana. error: got error while expanding auth.generic_oauth.client_secret with expander 'file': stat /etc/secrets/auth_generic_oauth/client_secret: no such file or directory
```

Am I doing something wrong? I guess in that case the file should be created automatically, shouldn't it?

Comment: Try more open `defaultMode` for the secret. For example `0444`.

Comment: Did you managed to fix?